# Make a textbox flat and blend into the page by removing border/glow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a textbox that seems to be confusing our users since they try to edit it and it's indellible. So I changed the background colour and removed the borders to basically just have it look like text on the screen.

Below you can see my screenshots with and without focus, as well as the HTML that defines the box and the LESS that styles it.

My question is how do I get rid of the faint blue border when out of focus and glow when in focus?

HTML:

```
<input class="span1 bg-light-blue" type="text" name="hand_unit_id" id="hand_unit_id" readonly="TRUE" />
```

LESS:

```
#hand_unit_id {
    border: none ! important;
}
#hand_unit_id:focus {
    border: none ! important;
    box-shadow: none ! important;
    outline: none ! important;
}
```

[image: Textbox no focus]
[image: Textbox with focus]

Comment: That looks like the browser's stylesheet (chrome) to me.

Comment: Yeah...the glow (box shadow?) Is probably being applied by the browser. When focused the box looks almost exactly as I want it (after editing to make "Focuss" read "Focus". But the main point is to make it blend into the page so the user is never really tempted to give it focus.

Comment: Another approach is to use jQuery to take the input's value and put it in a span, then hide the input.

Comment: I can't hide the value, the user needs it for reference at times, but when it looks like a textbox some of them think they need to edit it, even when it has a readonly=true and their cursor turns into the NO sign when hovering over it.

Comment: I don't think you understood my suggestion, but it sounds like you've resolved your issue. If not, let me know and I'll show you what I meant.

Comment: I went ahead and put it up in case it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way you might go about this that bypasses the whole styling issue altogether. It may have accessibility benefits as well. Screen reader users may get confused by your text field.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/NHV3g/2

```
<input id="my_text_box" type="text" value="Scruff" style="display: none;" />
<span id="my_text_span"></span>
```

Inside document.ready:

```
$('#my_text_span').text($('#my_text_box').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the LESS as follows resolves this issue. There seems to be a box shadow being applied to the textbox when it has no focus.

```
#hand_unit_id {
    border: none ! important;
    box-shadow: none ! important;
    outline: none ! important;
}
#hand_unit_id:focus {
    border: none ! important;
    box-shadow: none ! important;
    outline: none ! important;
}
```